# How to display all parent and child groups in one column in rdlc

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc-4, rdlc

Actullay i want to create a report that show data in below given form:

Fiscal Year: 1990
Catagory-1
Item -1
Item -2 
Catagory-2
Item -1
Catagory-2
Item -3

1- Fiscal year is parent then Category Name is its child and then ItemTitle is category name child.

I have created same but that was not required because child column display in the right column of the parent column.Thanks in advance.

Kindly tell me that which control will be the best option for this Table or Metrix

Comment: I wanted to display all in one column

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Add Table in report.
Click on row add parent group, a new parent group column will be added on right side.
click on parent group add row in this group.Delete new added column.
click on new add parent group add parent group as done before. delete this new added column.
All three parent child groups are in one column.